# How to fix hibernate / suspend with proprietary nVidia driver?

Tags: 10.10, suspend, hibernate, nvidia

I've just got an Dell Precision M6500 that comes with an nVidia card. Together with Kubunutu 10.10 and the proprietary nvidia driver suspend to disk or RAM does not work. It's allways ending with a running system and a locked screen (i.e. I can just enter my password and everything is as before - it's never sleeping)

Can someone please help me to debug this issue?
Where should I look for information? None of the log files seem to show an obvious error...

Comment: @Chris, did you ever get this solved? Please update your question. Thanks

Comment: Not that I expected it to work under Linux (hope is dying last..), but I would very much appreciate it if I wouldn't have to turn off the machine ever time I don't need it... So far my box doesn't even suspend when choosing suspend I just end up with a locked screen :(

Answer (score 1):

Updating my kernel to the latest version solved the problem for my 1215n Asus

Answer (score 0):

Try booting with `acpi=off` to see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch This is an answer. It suggests a course of action which may fix the problem, and which is intended to fix the problem. This is not a diagnostic step or any other sort of attempt to get information from the OP.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.